# Can't set a default date value for bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, default-value, bootstrap-datetimepicker

How can I set a default value for the bootstrap datetimepicker?

Here's my code:

```
jQuery(function () {

        var myStartDate = $('#myStartDate').val();

        jQuery('#startDate').datetimepicker({
            locale: 'de',
            format: 'dd, DD.MM.YYYY, HH:mm',
            minDate: moment(),          
        });
    });
```

The variable "myStartDate" is a java.util.date saved in an input hidden field. Is there parameter to set the default value? Any suggestions?

Comment: Use the `defaultDate` option (https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#defaultdate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `defaultDate`

```
    jQuery('#startDate').datetimepicker({
        locale: 'de',
        format: 'dd, DD.MM.YYYY, HH:mm',
        defaultDate: "11/1/2016",
        minDate: moment(),          
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the defaultDate method jQuery Datepicker as suggested by Rafael.And also i would suggest you to go through the api Documentation of jQuery Datepicker.

URL of documentation is as follow http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/